# How to Enable "joomla extension and apply to modules"

Tags: joomla-2.5

I installed this extension : http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/news-tickers-a-scrollers/6677

I installed this extension using : Extension Manager > Upload package file. It's installed successfully.

In Plug-in manager, I enabled It.

Than In Module manager, I created "Moving text" module and in "Custom output" , I entered the code :

{text =scrollig text }

But it's not working here you can visit this link and see in footer http://naadiastrology.info/

Why it's not working or how to use this extension.

please help me to find solution.

Comment: please help me, i am struggling for this.

Comment: I installed this extension : http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/news-tickers-a-scrollers/6677


I installed this extension using : Extension Manager > Upload package file. It's installed successfully.

In Plug-in manager, I enabled It.

Than In Module manager, I created "Moving text" module and in "Custom output" , I entered the code : 

<div class="movingObj">

{text =scrollig text }

</div>

But it's not working here you can visit this link and see in footer http://naadiastrology.info/

Why it's not working or how to use this extension.

Comment: hi, thanks alot for your help, I got the solution.